Generalization of $\mathsf{MAJSAT}$ to higher levels of the Counting Hierarchy
The problem of majority satisfiability $\mathsf{MAJSAT}$ is known to be complete for the first level $\mathsf{C_1P = PP}$ of the Counting Hierarchy  and $\mathsf{MAJMAJSAT}$ is known to be complete for the second level $\mathsf{C_2P = {PP}^{\mathsf{PP}}}$. These languages and further extensions can be defined inductively as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
    \mathsf{MAJSAT} & = \{ \varphi(x_1) \mid \varphi(a_1) \text{ is true for } \geq\frac{1}{2} \text{ of assignments } a_1 \text{ to } x_1 \} \\
    \mathsf{{MAJ}^{2}SAT} & = \{ \varphi(x_1, x_2) \mid \varphi(x_1, a_2) \in \mathsf{MAJSAT} \text{ for } \geq\frac{1}{2} \text{ of assignments } a_2 \text{ to } x_2 \} \\
    \mathsf{{MAJ}^{3}SAT} & = \{ \varphi(x_1, x_2, x_3) \mid \varphi(x_1, x_2, a_3) \in \mathsf{{MAJ}^2SAT} \text{ for } \geq\frac{1}{2} \text{ of assignments } a_3 \text{ to } x_3 \} \\
    & \:\:\vdots \\
    \mathsf{{MAJ}^{k}SAT} & = \{ \varphi(x_1, \dots, x_k) \mid \varphi(x, \dots, x_{k-1}, a_k) \in \mathsf{{MAJ}^{k-1}SAT} \text{ for } \geq\frac{1}{2} \text{ of assignments } a_k \text{ to } x_k \} \\
\end{align*}
$$
Notice that $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k$ can correspond to single variables or sets of variables as long as they are pair-wise disjoint, and notice also that $\mathsf{MAJMAJSAT} = \mathsf{{MAJ}^2SAT}$.
Is $\mathsf{{MAJ}^3SAT}$ a complete problem for the third level $\mathsf{C_3P = {PP}^{({PP}^{PP})}}$?
Furthermore, is there a generalization of these results for higher levels of the Counting Hierarchy? i.e. for every $k > 0$, is $\mathsf{{MAJ}^kSAT}$ a complete problem for the $k$-th level $\mathsf{C_kP}$?

Please make your question self-contained by including definitions of the problems you are asking about, in this case in particular define the problems $\textsf{MAJ}^k\textsf{SAT}$.

Thank you for the feedback. I edited the post to include an inductive definition of the problems :)
